# nvcc --ptxas-options=-v (register and memory usage) ERROR

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I want to compile my cuda program with --ptxas-options=-v flag of nvcc to achieve register and memory usage in order to use them in CUDA GPU Occupancy Calculator.

error: identifier "atomicAdd" is undefined

I have used atomicAdd in my kernel. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atomic operations are not supported by all GPU generations, and the default target for nvcc is sm_10. Assuming your GPU supports atomic operations (see the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation) for details of what features are supported by your GPU, appendix F.1) then you will need to target that architecture, e.g. `-gencode arch=compute_20,code=\'compute_20,sm_20\'` for Fermi and newer. See the [NVCC manual](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation) for more information on the gencode options.

BTW, does adding the `--ptxas-options=-v` flag actually change the behaviour? If not then the title of your question is misleading.

Comment: Atomic operations are supported by the GPU that I use. I have compiled my program by nvcc -arch=sm_20 test.cu -o test and got the right result. I just want to use the mentioned option in order to get register and shared memory usage of my program.

Comment: So your problem is fixed? In other words you don't get the error any more?

Comment: No, my problem has not been solved. I still have a problem with mentioned option. I cannot use the mentioned option to compile my program.

Comment: You will need to use both -arch=sm_20 and --ptxas-options=-v together. If that doesn't work, please post your full command line...

Comment: Do you mean that the issue is fixed when you have both options together?